# To get full path of powershell.exe programmatically

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I need to get the full path(absolute) of Powershell.exe to run powershell scripts in my code . Can anyone suggest me any library or inbuilt method to do this .

I tried boost filesystem's absolute() method and getFUllPathName() method in windows.h . But all i manage to get is the current working directory of my project .

Comment: I doubt that you need this. You can probably run your scripts directly with `ShellExecute`; it will find PowerShell for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively (if you don't like to rely on environment variables) you can also query the registry. Powershell, on installation, writes a FriendlyTypeName value, which, on my machine is

> @"%systemroot%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe", -107

which contains the path.

The registry key is `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellConsole.1\FriendlyTypeName`

Use the Windows API to query the registry.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**
Powershell.exe is most likely in your path, so you can just use this in your C++ code.

```
system("powershell.exe -Command .\\script.bat");
```

Just replace `.\\script.bat` by the path of your script.

**Solution 2:**
You could use an environment variable to get the path of powershell in your program.
Just set a environment variable called `PSPATH`, or something, in your system, with the path of your powershell directory (`C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`).
Then you can get it with the [`getenv()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/getenv/) function.

Example :

```
char* psVar = getenv("PSPATH");
if (psVar != NULL)
{
    std::string psPath = psVar;
    std::string psScript = ".\\script.bat";

    system(psPath + "\\powershell.exe -Command " + psScript);
}
```